# Using Flexbox to present 4 images in a ul as a 2x2 grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am refactoring non-responsive code and am trying to display the below code as a **2x2 grid** using **Flexbox**. I have tried using `display: flex`, `flex-flow: row-wrap`, but the images in my `ul` are acting as block elements and won't sit side by side.

Here is the original code:

```
<div class="gallery">
        <h2>Newest Products:</h2>
        <ul>
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt="First gallery image" /></li>
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt="Second gallery image" /></li>
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt="Third gallery image" /></li>
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt="Fourth gallery image" /></li>
        </ul>
     </div>

.gallery {
   clear: both;
}

.gallery ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 32px 0;
}

.gallery li {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 10px;
}

.gallery img {
   width: 280px;
   height: auto;
}
```

[image: What happens when using flexbox.]

This screenshot is what happened when I tried using this code:

```
.gallery {
clear: both;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.gallery ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 32px 0;
}
.gallery li {
margin: 0 10px;
flex-basis: 50%;
}
.gallery img {
width: 50%;
height: auto;
}
```

Again, all I want to do is place these images in a responsive 2x2 orientation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
.gallery {}

.gallery ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 32px 0;
}

.gallery li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);  /* width minus margins */
}

.gallery img {
    width: 100%;                   /* occupy 100% width of li container */
    height: auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpL1jv2n/)

NOTES:

- When you create a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element), the *child elements* become flex items. The descendants of the flex container beyond the children do not become flex items and, therefore, do not accept flex properties.

  In your code, `.gallery` is the flex container. This means that its children – `h2` and `ul` – are flex items.  However, the children of the `ul` are not flex items and flex properties don't apply. That's why the images, contained in the `li` elements, *"are acting as block elements and won't sit side by side"*.
- To apply flex properties to the `li` elements, their parent must be made a flex container. By adding `display: flex` to the `ul`, the `li`'s become flex items. (Note, the `img` elements remain inline elements because they are not children of the flex container.)

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly, and thank you for explaining how flex items work (and don't work!) @Michael

Comment: @Michael_B What exactly is defining that it wraps 2x2 when there is no container width? how would you go about if you wanted 3  top 3 bottom? I appreciate any input.

Comment: @SteveHartley  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);   - change 50% for whatrever you need

Comment: @SteveHartley, there is, in fact, a container width. It's 100% (the default, since there is no explicit width defined). Regardless, when you set a flex item to 50% width, that means it takes 50% of its parent's width, whatever that may be. In other words, the container can have any width. The flex item will take 50% of it, thus accommodating two per row.

Comment: As @vals said, to change the number of flex items per row, adjust their width. If you want ***one*** per row, set their width to 100% [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpL1jv2n/1/). If you want ***three*** per row, the width would be ~33% [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpL1jv2n/3/). ***Four*** per row: 25% [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpL1jv2n/4/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Ohhh I get it now thankyou so much.  And Val. I will research some more on flex-basis.  Great explanation thanks for your time.