# Creating a 2x2 grid of Font Awesome icons and text beneath using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive 2x2 grid of Font Awesome icons with text beneath, both centered within their containing **li** element. I'm currently trying to use [a method that I used when I was doing something similar with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388573/using-flexbox-to-present-4-images-in-a-ul-as-a-2x2-grid) within a list using Flexbox but it doesn't seem to work the same.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<section id="services">
    <h2>What we do best:</h2>
    <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li>
         <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
           <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
         <p>Application Support</p>
      </li>

      <li>
         <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
           <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-users fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
         <p>User Training</p>
      </li>

      <li>
         <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
           <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-headphones fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
         <p>SharePoint Consulting</p>
      </li>

      <li>
         <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
           <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-magic fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
         <p>Custom Development</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </section>
```

And CSS:

```
#services{
margin: 0 auto;
}

#services h2{
margin-left: 1rem;
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 2rem;
}

#services ul{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#services li{
margin: .55rem;
font-size: .85rem;
flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.fa-circle{
color: #30C0D8;
}
```

That code has gotten me here:
[image]

Will this method work for this situation or is there a better way? For some reason, as a side note, when I expand the window my 2nd column of icons moves whereas the 1st column of icons stay put. Any ideas why that would be? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `text-align: center;` will help you for `#services li`

Comment: Funny enough, that seemed to fix everything. Everything within the li centered. Thanks Harish!