# Row not wrapping using SASS

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

html code

```
<div class="pro" *ngFor="let home of homeds">
  <div *ngFor="let homer of home.teachers">
     <img src="{{ homer.img }}" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

And my SASS code

```
.pro{
    img{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
}
```

Instead of the top first image this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Check if the width of the images is more than half the width of the container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Flexbox to present 4 images in a ul as a 2x2 grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388573/using-flexbox-to-present-4-images-in-a-ul-as-a-2x2-grid)

Comment: @Vandesh I have checked and that seem not to be the issue.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a plunker somehow? Will be easier to check

Comment: @NonameSL it an ionic 3 using *ngFor to show images from the db and not static.

Comment: @GeraldBrigen The styles won't differ, it doesn't matter. The SCSS compiles into CSS which works on the plain rendered HTML. It's the same styling.

Comment: Sass is not really relevant to this question. The selector you are using is so simple there's not even really a point to use Sass for that, because in this case, Sass is actually making you write *more* than vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your html markup you need modify sass to be

```
.pro{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    >div {max-width:50%;flex:1 1 100%;}
    img{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `display: flex` rule is on the wrong element.  I'm not too familiar with angular, but I imagine the final html looks something like this:

```
<div class="pro">
    <div>
        <img src="home_teacher_1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="home_teacher_2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="home_teacher_3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="home_teacher_4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

If that's the case you'd want `display: flex` and `flex-flow: row wrap` on `.pro div` not `.pro img`.

```css
.pro {
    width: 1000px;
}

.pro div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="pro">
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Confirming that `display: flex` is on the wrong element. It needs to be on the parent (in this case `div`)